# WP8 LongListSelector - Navigating to different pages

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I have recently created a LongListSelector for my Windows Phone 8 app. However what I want to achieve now is to navigate to another page when the user taps on an item but I don't know what put in my code and also I'm not 100% as to where I should insert my uri's for each individual page. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this matter.

Many thanks.

```
Partial Public Class Station_Chooser
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim source As New List(Of Glasgow)()
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Bridge Street"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Buchanan Street"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Cessnock"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Cowcaddens"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Govan"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Hillhead"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Ibrox"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Kelvinbridge"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Kelvinhall"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Kinning Park"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Patrick"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("Shields Road"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("St Enoch"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("St George's Cross"))
        source.Add(New Glasgow("West Street"))


        Dim DataSource As List(Of AlphaKeyGroup(Of Glasgow)) = AlphaKeyGroup(Of Glasgow).CreateGroups(source, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, Function(s As Glasgow)
                                                                                                                                                                          Return s.Station
                                                                                                                                                                      End Function, True)
        GlasgowSubway.ItemsSource = DataSource

    End Sub

    Public Class Glasgow
        Public Property Station() As String
            Get
                Return m_Station
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_Station = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Station As String

        Public Sub New(station As String)
            Me.Station = station
        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to do that. One of them shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14233188/2998271), maybe not the best or the most beautiful way but a very simple one.

> Attach event handler for `SelectionChanged`, add command for navigating to new page in the handler, set `SelectedItem = null`

I assumed that the destination page is same page for any item selected, only different content/data displayed. You need to pass selected item's signature in the Uri parameter to enable destination page to display information accordingly. For example :

```
NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri("/nextpage.xaml?selectedStation=" & selectedItem.Station, UriKind.Relative))
```

**UPDATE :**

As you clarified that destination page will be different for each item, my previous answer still valid. Only the later part need to be modified, not using Uri parameter.
So this is what I think. Add another property in `Glasgow` class, say it `StationId`. Upon initialization :

```
//the second parameter is StationId value
source.Add(New Glasgow("Bridge Street", "BridgeStreet"))
```

Then name each page with pattern **StationId.xaml**, so page for *Bridge Street* should be `BridgeStreet.xaml`. With that, in `SelectionChanged` event handler you can navigate to corresponding page without using `Select Case selectedItem.Station ...`:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(selectedItem.StationId & ".xaml", UriKind.Relative))
```

Note : Having more then one properties in the model (`Station` and `StationId` in this case) require you to specify which property to display in `LongListSelector`. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20719714/2998271) to know how, if you don't know yet.

Comment: In response to your answer, the destination page is not the same. There are 15 intended destinations, each of them have their own uri/page.

Comment: @m.findlay93 updated my answer to deal with different Uri for each item

Comment: Each of my pages already have a name.xaml, would it work if I used a tap event like in this other post of mine (like I did for my WP7 project)?: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299801/longlistselector-not-working-not-navigating-to-other-pages/19306646?noredirect=1#19306646

Comment: yes it should work. And btw that was very close if I can't say same question with this :p

Comment: Brilliant! It works! Thanks a lot. Do you want me to mention you in the 'Thanks to' page of my app?

Comment: @m.findlay93 That would be an honor :)

Comment: OK will do :-) Happy Holidays